# LaTeX with embedded in-line code blocks and AucTeX

Tags: emacs, org-mode, auctex, org-babel

I am writing LaTeX in my org file with embedded code evaluation using `src_lang` [in-line code blocks](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html#sec-5-4) (in my case, lang=lisp).  This works fine when using bare LaTeX for export, but I would like AUCTeX editing and highlighting which are not available with bare LaTeX in the org file.  The only way I can see to get AUCTeX is to use a [LaTeX source code block](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-LaTeX.html); this does what I want, but now the inline code blocks are not expanded; instead, they are exported literally to the LaTeX.  Is there a way to have an exportable LaTeX source code block that expands in-line code blocks on export, or somehow have the AuCTeX editing features with in-line src_lang code blocks that get expanded?

Example:

```
* This is an example
#+BEGIN_SRC latex
This is an example.  The sum of 2 and 2 is $src_lisp{(+ 2 2)}$.
#+END_SRC
```

produces (removing a lot of preamble for clarity)

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
\vspace*{1cm}
\section{This is an example}
\label{sec-1}

This is an example.  The sum of 2 and 2 is $src_lisp{(+ 2 2)}$.

\end{document}
```

whereas

```
* This is an example
This is an example.  The sum of 2 and 2 is $src_lisp{(+ 2 2)}$.
```

produces

```
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
\vspace*{1cm}
\section{This is an example}
\label{sec-1}

This is an example.  The sum of 2 and 2 is $=4=$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have an example org file demonstrating what you've tried.

Comment: I've added an example that shows what I mean; ignore the equal signs in the result, I know how to fix that.

Comment: I don't have a good answer, but you can toggle between LaTeX-mode and org-mode.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very late answer, but I think [CDLaTeX](http://orgmode.org/manual/CDLaTeX-mode.html) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. CDLaTeX looks interesting. I will have to investigate.